# How to create an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

After hours of research, I cannot figure out how to make a 161x101 array in JavaScript. I feel like this should be JavaScript 101, but I can't figure it out.

This is what happen when I try the most logical thing to do.

```
<head>
<script>
var StopTimes = [161,101];
StopTimes[1][1] = "TEST";
StopTimes[33][64] = "TEST2";
console.log(StopTimes[1][1]);
console.log(StopTimes[33][64]);
console.log(StopTimes[15][3]);
</script>
</head>
```

Error Message:

[image]

I've spent hours trying other things, but nothing works. Am I just stupid? What do I do to make a 161x101 array?

Comment: `StopTimes` is an array containing two items, numbers. `StopTimes[1]` refers to a number. Assigning to the `[1]` property of a number doesn't make any sense

Comment: And to create the array of `n` size https://stackoverflow.com/a/966938/600486

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Comment: //this would create the two-dimensional array of the size you specified.
`StopTimes = Array.from(Array(161),() => new Array(101)); `
//assign what ever value you want for specified index.
`StopTimes[1][1] = "TEST";
StopTimes[33][64] = "TEST2";`

Answer (score 0):

can easily use

```
 var StopTimes=new Array(161);
 
 StopTimes.foreach(function(item,index){StopTimes[index]=new Array(101)  });
```

Comment: it is recommended to not answer duplicate question to avoid adding noise to the site

Answer (score 0):

```
var StopTimes = [];
for (var i = 0; i< 161; i++){
  var tmp = [];
  for(var j=0; j<101; j++){
     tmp.push(0);//or any data element
   }
  StopTimes.push(tmp);
}
```

Comment: it is recommended to not answer duplicate question to avoid adding noise to the site